# Unable to use AWS Developer Support

Tags: amazon-web-services

First time I am trying to use 'AWS Developer Support' plan (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/compare-plans/) where they have mentioned to give technical support through "Business hours** access to Cloud Support Associates via email". [image: AWS support plans]

But I am unable to get any support, even I dont have any e-mail ID to contact them.

On the support page it shows "Basic Plan" [image: Support page]

Which I have already upgraded to "Developer plan" [image: Developer Plan]

Is there any setting I need to change?
How can I contact them?

Answer (score 0):

To write for support you must go to [Support Center > Create Case](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home?region=eu-west-1#/case/create)

Accessed through AWS Panel > Support (Top right corner menu) > Support Center > Create Case

[image: How to access]

---

Maybe you have not confirmed plan change yet (at the bottom of page when changing plan)? Or maybe Amazon has still to process your request. Try writing to support about your case.